# Yoast Seo noindex added to pages outside wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I have called the wordpress theme header outside wordpress to serve static pages. Unfortunately the Yoast plugin now it is adding the noindex meta tag to those pages, therefore those pages are not indexed by the google bot now can any body help me with this? thanks!

Comment: What exactly did you do? Did you just `require("..../header.php")`? Please show some code.

Comment: This is how the header is called: define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php');
get_header();       It seems that because the pages that are using these header live outside wordpress then yoast seo identifies them as 404 or search type of page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wpseo_robots` filter ([yoast documentation](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/)) to override that. Add something like

```
add_filter("wpseo_robots", function() { return "index, follow"; });
```

before calling get_header() to overwrite what wpseo sets. Don't put it in the functions.php of your theme, though, or it will be used on everything in WP.